# Rails 5 Accessing Assets from Coffee Files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to access an image from a coffee file. I can get it to work in development, but not production. The ruby on rails guide for doing this doesn't seem to work.  In production digesting is interfering with the paths.

Section 2.3.3 of the page below is supposed to work:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

This is my code:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('.ui.embed').embed({
    source      : 'youtube',
    id          : 'l5m3CW1oWg0',
    placeholder : "<%= asset_path 'overlook4@2x.jpg' %>"
  })
```

The error from browser console:

> Blockquote  [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://yyyyy.com/assets/overlook4@2x.jpg

Notice there is no md5 appended to the jpeg file so it can't find the compiled file.

My question is what is the CORRECT fix for this?  Would it be ok to turn off digests in production?  I find that it breaks too much stuff.

Comment: If you `rake assets:precompile`, do you get a version of that with the correct asset url?

Comment: No.  I believe it's the way rails 4 and 5 handles digesting now.  In this situation you just have to add that asset to your public directory.